# What are the methods of fluoride removal from drinking water?

Tags: water, water-treatment

I would like to remove fluoride from my water supply.

Are there any methods, any test kits or water distillation units to remove fluoride from drinking water?

See also:

- [Is there any at home test for fluoride levels in your water, and what is the best water distillation unit?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110824093408AA5tigC)
- [A simple and easy way to neutralize fluorides in drinking water](http://www.tunemind.net/fluorides.htm)
- [Scientists Discover New Technique to Remove Fluoride from Drinking Water](http://www.trueactivist.com/scientists-discover-new-technique-to-remove-fluoride-from-drinking-water/)

Read More: http://www.trueactivist.com/scientists-discover-new-technique-to-remove-fluoride-from-drinking-water/

Comment: Freezing removes a lot of flouride. No idea where it goes. Can anyone help?

Comment: If water is partially frozen the ice is usually much purer than the water because the soluble materials remain in the remaining liquor.

Comment: Fluoride is very rarely a problem in water supply. It is added in small quantities for health reasons in many areas. There is no need to remove it (unless you hold the *Pure Bodily Fluids* philosophy of General Jack D Ripper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many filters which **do not** remove fluoride from potable water. Boiling or freezing does not help either. Reverse osmosis filtration may be a solution. However they are expensive ($100+).

Activated alumina defluoridation filters are used in areas where contamination from fluoride is common. These can reduce fluoride levels from 0.5 ppm to 0.1 ppm, but these require frequent replacement and are not a solution for domestic treatment. Distillation filters can be purchased to remove fluoride.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is probably partial freezing and collecting the ice. Most soluble material will remain in the liquid. Distillation from a basic solution should retain fluoride Add some washing soda, Na2CO3 or TSP. Reverse osmosis [check with the manufacturer] followed by mixed bed ion exchange removes almost all ionics.

Amazon sells test kits ~$30 that allegedly test for almost everything.

Another thought! Winter is approaching collect ice from a clean frozen stream or lake and boil it before drinking.

Comment: Another idea collect rain, allow the entrained dust to settle, boil before dinking. Cistern water thru a RO gives superb drinking water, use the reject for washing and flushing.